# Given a knockout model, thoughts on how to generate alphabetic index

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a list of contacts like:

```
  1 Mon
  Bob
  Brett
  Brad
  Kathy
  Zelda
```

It's easy enough with KnockoutJS to display that list after applying a model or using a jQuery template.

What I'm interested in doing now is dynamically showing headers, like the way it works on the iPhone, meaning the output would look like:

```
#
  1 Mon
B
  Bob
  Brett
  Brad
K
  Kathy
Z  
  Zelda
```

Any thoughts on how to cleverly accomplish this with Knockout w/o having to hardcode a header for each alphanumeric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered your question on the KO forums here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/knockoutjs/VgDnxb_jB7c/discussion

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/MZN6u/

I created a dependentObservable with a structure that you can map to your view (template) easily, which is an array of objects that each have a `letter` property and a `contacts` array.

dependentObservable looks like:

```
viewModel.contactsByLetter = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    var letterIndex = [];
    var result = [];
    //sort the contacts
    var sortedContacts = this.contacts().sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.name().toUpperCase() > b.name().toUpperCase() ? 1 : -1; 
    });
    //loop through each contact and put it with its letter
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(sortedContacts, function(contact) {
        //grab first character
        var firstLetter = contact.name().charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        //if it is a number use #
        if (!isNaN(firstLetter)) {
            firstLetter = "#";
        }

        //do we already have entries for this letter
        if (!letterIndex[firstLetter]) {
            //new object to track this letter's contacts
            var letterContacts = {
                letter: firstLetter,
                contacts: []
            };
            letterIndex[firstLetter] = letterContacts ; //easy access to it
            result.push(letterContacts); //add it to the array that we will return
        }

        //at this point we should have an object to push our contact to
        letterIndex[firstLetter].contacts.push(contact);
    });

    return result;
}, viewModel);
```

Comment: Thanks RP, it looks good but I think Alex's solution is a little cleaner. thoughts?

Comment: You could make either way work.  My answer was intended for use by Knockout in templates.  The result of his is an object that has properties for each letter.  The result of mine is an array that you can easily use with the foreach option of the template binding in KO (foreach won't loop through properties of an object).  That is the reason for slightly more code.  I was also assuming that your contacts are objects and not an array of strings.

Comment: Good call. Trying it now. So far bugs are that if name is null, it errors, which given a contact list of (firstname, lastname, email) is possible... Also for some reason when you output contactsModel.contactsByLetter() the headers are not sorted, shows Y Z G , instead of #, A,B,E,Z etc....

Comment: They should be sorted.  Is it any different than from my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/MZN6u/

Comment: I updated the sorting.  Should do a toUpperCase() on the letters and return -1 or 1.  Let me know if you need assistance with handling the name being null.

Comment: How would you sugget handling the name being null?

Comment: I guess you could handle it several ways.  Without introducing new variables you could just change the sorting to: 

    var sortedContacts = this.contacts().sort(function(a, b) {
        return (a.name() || "").toUpperCase() > ( b.name() || "").toUpperCase() ? 1 : -1; 
    });

and do this in the loop on contacts: 
        //grab first character
        var firstLetter = (contact.name() || "").charAt(0).toUpperCase();

Fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/MZN6u/

Comment: RP, one last question... Right now # comes at the top of the list. Is there a way to get # at the bottom? ie, A-Z, #

Comment: Hmm turns out this is harder than I thought !

Comment: I updated my fiddle with a change to the sorting function: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/MZN6u/.  Not sure if you got your answer or not from the other question.

Answer (score 3):

- Sort them naturally in case they are not already.
- Create a new object to hold the new data organised.
- Loop through the sorted array, creating an array for each new group encountered.
- Append the contact based on its group.

```
contacts.sort();
var contactsGrouped = {};
$.each(contacts, function(index, contact) {
   var first = contact.substr(0, 1),
       group = first.match(/\d+/) ? '#' : first;

  if (contactsGrouped[group] === undefined) {
      contactsGrouped[group] = [];
  }

  contactsGrouped[group].push(contact);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/hZKYg/).

It may be worth calling `$.trim()` if you are unsure whether there may be leading/trailing whitespace on the contacts.

Also, if you want to create blank arrays for `#` and `a-z`, simply loop through `'#abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('')` first and set the blank arrays.

Also, if you want the properties to be uppercase, simply call `toUpperCase()` method before setting the property.

Comment: @AnApprentice It creates the contacts grouped under your requirement. You could then iterate through it and build any HTML.

Comment: Thanks that's very clean. How would you loop over the array, not knowing what is in the array if anything?

Comment: @AnApprentice If you mean the resulting array, you could use jQuery's [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Comment: What is contactsGrouped doing?

Comment: @AnApprentice Just being an object with some properties. I guess just hangin' out, waiting for someone to iterate over it :)